# プログラムがwebに対応されない

Tags: python, python3

質問が頓珍漢でしたら申し訳ありません。（当方理解が及ばない中チャレンジ中です）

Webブラウザに「My first CGI !」と表示するプログラムを作成しています。
HTTPレスポンスを返すプログラムは以下の通りです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python

html_body='''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CGI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  My first CGI!
 </body>
</html>'''

print("Content-type:text/html")
print(")
print(html_body)
```

こちらのプログラムをターミナル上で実行するために以下のコードを打ち込み実行トライしました。

```
chmod +x my_first_cgi.py
./my_first_cgi.py
```

すると以下のエラーが出ました。

```
-bash: ./my_first_cgi.py: /usr/bin/env/: bad interpreter: Not a directory
```

どのように改善すれば良いのかご教授ください。
また質問の意図、言葉の使い方等が間違っていると思われます。
ご指導していただきたく質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 失礼します。なぜか'''の後のコードが反映されません。

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env/ python

html_body='''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CGI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  My first CGI!
 </body>
</html>'''

print("Content-type:text/html")
print(")
print(html_body)

Comment: このような形で書かせていただきました。
コメントからで恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少なくとも以下のように修正する必要があります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

html_body='''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CGI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  My first CGI!
 </body>
</html>'''

print("Content-type:text/html")
print("")
print(html_body)
```

エラーの直接的な原因は、１行目の`env`の後にスラッシュ（`/`）があることです。15行目もダブルクォーテーションが１つなので構文エラーになります。

> 失礼します。なぜか'''の後のコードが反映されません。

質問にソースコードなどを書くときは、該当部分を選択して<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>をクリックして下さい。それにより、インデントされて見やすい書式になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
無事にHTTPのレスポンスが返ってきました。
本当に感謝です。

Comment: @Yuki 他の質問に関してもそうですが、回答が得られたら、その回答を承認するようにして下さい。

Comment: インデントに関しまして承知しました。
ありがとうございます。

承認に関しましても教えていただきありがとうございます。
承認の方法はチェックマークをクリックでよろしいでしょうか？
（こちらの回答は承認できていますでしょうか）

Comment: @Yuki はい。それでOKです。